# MS Exchange Server 2010 - Delivery notifications?

Tags: exchange-2010

I was installing (for the first time), Microsoft Exchange Server 2010, and everything works fine but every time they send an email - using Outlook - there is a boring delivery status notification message:

> **Delivery to these recipients or groups is complete, but no delivery notification was sent by the destination server:**

I was searching the internet but so far I weren't able to find a concrete solution..

Any suggestions regarding what might cause such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just a delivery notification in outlook. Got to Tools -> Options -> Email Options -> Tracking Options and un-check the box that says "Delivery receipt".

Comment: Hmmm could be.. I guess I will have to deploy such option via Group Policy... I will report on the progress.. thanks for the tip :)